# Spring + Swagger2 + HashMap JSON

Tags: java, json, spring, swagger, swagger-ui

I have a service that has a HashMap receiving the json from the client

```
public ResponseEntity<?> trocarSenha(@RequestBody HashMap<String, String> json)
```

Is there any way to tell to swagger what I expect receive? I would like Swagger show something like this [image]

Answer (score 1):

In your case, assuming it's a fixed set of attributes your expecting, I would recommend using `@ModelAttribute` instead of `@ResponseBody` and using a concrete bean class with the getters and setters for the properties you wish to expose.

The catch is if u want to add additional properties that are not visible to the consumer but only to the server u might have to do some work.

***NOTE:*** if the properties you wish to add are not conforming the bean spec (getters & setters) it will not be included.

Comment: Hi,Thank you for reply.
If doesn't exist another way to map what I would like to receive I'll create a bean class to wrap this, but I think if exists some way to map a JSON that we would like to receive and use @RequestBody with HashMap will be a better approach. 

Another question, when I have a huge Entity but want to expose to Swagger only a few attributes, is it possible?